# Changing zoom extent of streets in Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl, tippecanoe

Mapbox has limitations (such as zoom level 11 for road-street). I'm wondering how I can change that to 10. I want to use the same Mapbox-Streets-v8 tileset, just change that one zoom extent.

I have seen a bunch of answers involving MTS/tippecanoe, and gone through the tutorials on MapBox's website. I know I can create a tileset from scratch using data. But is there a way for me to replicate MapBox's streets-v8 and modify the zoom extent of roads, without having to recreate the entire tileset?

[road-street zoom level 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sA16T.jpg)

[road-street at zoom level 11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdSHf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in two ways

1. Eject the `road network` component and change the zoom extent for road-street

[image]
[image]

but by doing this the ejected layers will be ungrouped and you'll need to group it again(if you want)

[image]
[image]

2. Or you can add the same layer manually, change the zoom extent and apply the same style

[image]

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work. There seems to be a built-in limit in mapbox-streets-v8, where road-streets can't be viewed until zoom 11. See pictures in my post that I added